# Getting specific parent element using jQuery using eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to dynamically update a quantity field when I click on a '+' (Plus Button) However, depending where I click on the button, I am getting a different result for the parent element.

The HTML that is in use to call the function is below. This is HTML from my frontend developer and I am trying to connect a few things to make this work.

```html
<div id="item-list" class="product_list_container">
    <div class="bluedog-flex-container noPaddingLeftRgt payhub-well col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12" data-id="32" style="margin-top:0;">
        <div class="subtotal-div col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="bluedog-inner-flex-container product_info_container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="order-overview-left noPaddingLeft alignLeft col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">Macbook Pro @ 50.00</div>
                <div class="quantity_range_div col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="value-button createPage_decrease_qty decrease_value_btn" style="display:inline;" onclick="decreaseQty(event)"><i class="far fa-minus"></i></div>
                    <input type="number" class="itm_qty" id="number" value="1">
                    <div class="value-button increase_value_btn" style="display:inline;" onclick="increaseQty(event)"><i class="far fa-plus"></i></div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="item_price" data-qty="1" data-prod-name="Macbook Pro" data-id="32" data-tax="0" value="50.00"><a class="popup-close-btn order-overview-right close_btn_plans col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" onclick="removeItem(event)"> <i class="far fa-times-circle hosted_small_delete"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is, when I click on the Plus Button, (Screenshot attached) https://prnt.sc/oq770q the value will increase.

Originally, I was just using the following code to try and get the parent DIV id, which in this case is **item-list**

`var master = $(e.target).parents().eq(5).attr('id'); // Name of item-list container`

However, was receiving unexpected results, whereby if I tapped on the outside of the plus button, the surround grey area, it would not increase, but only if I tapped directly on the plus icon itself.

I noticed it was picking up a different element and the **eq(5)** was returning an undefined value. As you will see in in the script below, I have put in an if statement for a class check to see which part of the button has been pressed and this returns the expected results.

However, I dont' see this as scalable and transferable if someone was to change the FontAwesome Tag, as the class would likely be different.

```
function increaseQty(e) {

        var clicked = e.path[0];
        if ($(clicked).hasClass('fa-plus')) { 
            var master = $(e.target).parents().eq(5).attr('id'); // Name of item-list container
        } else {
            var master = $(e.target).parents().eq(4).attr('id'); // Name of item-list container
        }        

        var input  = $(e.target).parent().parent().find('input.itm_qty');
        var qty    = $(input).val();
        var newQty = parseInt(qty) + 1;
        $(input).val(newQty);
        updatePrices(master);
    }
```

I would like to know how, if possible, that regardless where on the container that is being clicked, the plus icon or the gray area around it, to increase the value, without having to do a dirty class check.

Many thanks, 
David.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you html code I am seeing like

```
<input type="number" class="itm_qty" id="number" value="1">
```

In this line you have id number so you can easily update.Based on your description your above line repeat. So you modify your increaseQty like that.

```
 function increaseQty(e) {
    var input  = $(e.target).prev('input.itm_qty');
    var qty    = $(input).val();
    var newQty = parseInt(qty) + 1;
    $(input).val(newQty);
    updatePrices(master);
}
```

If you see in your code increaseQty bind with div element and input itm_qty is sibling of div. So I am hoping above code works.

Comment: Whilst this refactors some of the code and helps me update the input.itm_qty, I am trying to better understand the best way to get the DIV which has the ID of 'item-list' without having to use an IF statement to to check if the FontAwesome was clicked (<i></i> element) or the outer container of the FontAwesome Icon (<div class="value-button increase_value_btn"></div> element). 

Right now, I am using the .parents().eq(4) or .parents().eq(5) to find the parent div. 

I am using this to assign the ID to  var master so I can pass this to the updatePrices function.

Comment: I have also noticed that using .prev() gives me the same results as parents().eq()

If I click on the FontAwesome Element (<i></i>) the prev() is picking up the div and not the input. I'm somewhat confused on the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question, with some help from @Dhiren (Thank You)

I found out that I could assign FontAwesome Icon to the class of a SPAN. Therefore I have changed the Divs which contained the FontAwesome Icons to Spans, and assigned the FA Icon class to the span, removing the  element.

```html
<div class="quantity_range_div col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    <span class="value-button createPage_decrease_qty decrease_value_btn far fa-minus" style="display:inline;" onclick="decreaseQty(event)"></span>
    <input type="number" class="itm_qty" id="number" value="1">
    <span class="value-button increase_value_btn far fa-plus" style="display:inline;" onclick="increaseQty(event)"></span>
</div>
```

In doing so I was able to use a single parents().eq(4) line of code, as the target will now always be a span, and not a Div element or an  element.

```
function increaseQty(e) {
        var master = $(e.target).parents().eq(4).attr('id'); 
        var input  = $(e.target).prev('input.itm_qty');
        var qty    = $(input).val();
        var newQty = parseInt(qty) + 1;
        $(input).val(newQty);
        updatePrices(master);
    }
```

Dhiren, thank you for the prev() suggestion as it has helped me better refactor not only this function, but more also! I appreciate the help and support.

- David